# How to set cookieJar in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, k6

In K6, I am setting `cookieJar` as below

```
  const jar = http.cookieJar();
  jar.set('https://auth.mygateid.test', 'oktaStateToken', oktaStateToken);
```

Is there a way to do this in JMeter ? Is it really required in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in JMeter it's sufficient just to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan and it will automatically take care of all incoming cookies, i.e. extract values from the [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) of the response and add them to [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header of the request if the cookie is valid (domain/path match, not expired, etc.)

It is also possible to manually add cookie if you need:

[image]

More information: [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter)